# Docking Panel resizable and scroll container

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How can Docking Panel be made resizable? How to create scroll container in Docking Panel?

I have extended Docking Panel with the Simple Panel given in this answer [How to create a Docking Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543507/how-to-create-a-docking-panel). So ideal would be know how to make them in

```
SimplePanel.prototype.initialize = function()
```

or somewhere when creating the docking panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the Extension mechanism, that way you can define JavaScript file that self-contain it. Here is an example. Now the **style.resize="auto"** line of code and how you can **appendChild** with other elements (e.g. a DIV full of other elements). With this extension you just need to call **viewer.loadExtension()**.

```
AutodeskNamespace('Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension');

Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MyExtension = function (viewer, options) {
  Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.call(this, viewer, options);

  var _self = this;

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // load callback
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  _self.load = function () {

    // need to access geometry? wait until is loaded
    viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, function () {
      createDockPanel();
    });

    return true;
  };

  var _dockPanel;

  function createDockPanel() {
    _dockPanel = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel(viewer.container, 'ecom', 'Cart');

    _dockPanel.container.style.top = "10px";
    _dockPanel.container.style.left = "10px";

    _dockPanel.container.style.width = "auto";
    _dockPanel.container.style.height = "auto";
    _dockPanel.container.style.resize = "auto";

    _dockPanel.container.appendChild(document.getElementById(‘someOtherElement’)); // for instance, a DIV

    _dockPanel.setVisible(true);
  }


  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // unload callback
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  _self.unload = function () {
    _dockPanel.setVisible(false)
    return true;
  };
};

Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MyExtension.prototype = Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.prototype);

Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MyExtension.prototype.constructor = Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MyExtension;

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MyExtension', Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MyExtension);
```